# Generate Midpoints for multiple Polygons along specified edges

Tags: arcgis-pro, midpoint

I often have a series of polygons(rectangles) that I need to add midpoints to. The midpoints will be on a separate point layer placed at either end - see below. I have been doing this manually either in CAD or ARCGIS PRO. I do not have a Data Management license, which I believe would solve this issue. Is there a way to batch generate these points so I don't have to go clicking on each polygon? I have generated points along lines, but as each polygon is 1.8m x 30m wide, the points don't land where i want them to, or I have to specify a point distance of 0.3m which covers each polygon in vertices I don't want. I'm sure there is a way around this but I'm not thinking it through properly.  Can anyone offer some advice?

[image]

Comment: All polygons have only four vertices?

Comment: Are you asking to create the two black points as separate points in a separate layer or actually insert them into the vertex sequence of the polygon. So as @BERA points out a rectangle will typically have just 4 vertices, are you wanting to create a rectangle with 6 vertices? Finally what logic are you using to select the sides of the rectangle you wish to create the points at? Edit\improve your question, don't just reply to this comment.

Comment: I would convert the polygons to lines, split the lines at vertices to create four lines per rectangle, select the two short sides, generate centroids. Should be possible to build a model to do this

Comment: HI BERA - This is a great idea - will give it a try.